# how do I close a redis connection using the sinatra streaming api?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, redis, publish-subscribe

I have the following sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'redis'
require 'json'


class FeedStream < Sinatra::Application


  helpers do
    include SessionsHelper

    def redis
      @redis ||= Redis.connect
    end
  end

  get '/feed', provides: 'text/event-stream' do


    stream do |out|

      redis.subscribe "feed" do |on|

        on.message do |channel, message|
          event_data = JSON.parse message
          logger.info "received event = #{event_data}"
          out << "event: #{event_data['event']}\n"
          out << "data: #{{:data => event_data['data'],
                           :by => current_user}}.to_json\n\n"
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

basically, it receives events published by other users to a feed using redis pubsub, and then it sends those events with the sinatra streaming api.
The problem is that, when the browser reconnects to the feed, the redis client keeps connected, and it keeps receiving events, so the redis server gets full of useless connections.
how can i close all this connections once the broser closes the connection to the web server?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have run in to a similar problem in Rails, and have [posted a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18970458/877472). The question includes a potential solution, which does work but is very goofy.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while.

Were you looking for [quit](http://rubydoc.info/gems/redis/2.2.0/Redis#quit-instance_method)?

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately, i need a way to tell if the browser already closed the connection to the server, then i would call `quit`

Answer (score 1):

After much research and experimentation, here's the code I'm using with sinatra + sinatra sse gem (which should be easily adapted to Rails 4):

```
class EventServer < Sinatra::Base
 include Sinatra::SSE
 set :connections, []
 .
 .
 .
 get '/channel/:channel' do
 .
 .
 .
  sse_stream do |out|
    settings.connections << out
    out.callback {
      puts 'Client disconnected from sse';
      settings.connections.delete(out);
    }
  redis.subscribe(channel) do |on|
      on.subscribe do |channel, subscriptions|
        puts "Subscribed to redis ##{channel}\n"
      end
      on.message do |channel, message|
        puts "Message from redis ##{channel}: #{message}\n"
        message = JSON.parse(message)
        .
        .
        .
        if settings.connections.include?(out)
          out.push(message)
        else
          puts 'closing orphaned redis connection'
          redis.unsubscribe
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The redis connection blocks on.message and only accepts (p)subscribe/(p)unsubscribe commands. Once you unsubscribe, the redis connection is no longer blocked and can be released by the web server object which was instantiated by the initial sse request.  It automatically clears when you receive a message on redis and sse connection to the browser no longer exists in the collection array.